# Displaying HTML file in Java ME?

Tags: java-me

For a newbie to J2ME, I have a basic task: display an HTML file.

How can you do this with J2ME?

Answer (score 1):

You can't display html file in jme, at least you shouldn't.

html files can be opened in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Emulating an HTML form in a J2ME application](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/htmlemulate/)

But a good way is to try out [j2mehtml](http://www.j2mehtml.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [HTML component](http://www.nextgenmoco.com/2010/05/css-support-added-to-htmlcomponent.html) in LWUIT