# how to load local html file in to j2me?

Tags: java, java-me

suppose i have one html file.




Hello World

how i can load this file to browser in j2me.
anyhelp

thankx

Comment: You already asked this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481282/displaying-html-file-in-java-me

Answer (score 0):

There is [platformRequest method](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=705498), but I'm not sure what phones supports opening local files. There is also CHAPI and it maybe provides some way to do such things, but it is probably not widely supported.